# Validation Regex for quantities with centesimal and without centesimal ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello to the community I have a query, I need a validation Regex, for amounts without decimals, that consider valid the following structure.

**99,999,999**

If I add a value:

```
12345678        -> Ok
12,345,678      -> Ok   
123,456,789     -> Failed
123,45,6,78     -> Failed
12,345,678.50   -> Failed
12,456,7ab      -> Failed
```

I have only been able to validate the size of 8 numerical characters:

```
var regex8 = /^-?([0-9]{1,8})?$/;
```

I wait for your comments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of work you can craft a pattern to do this:

https://regex101.com/r/DKpSUR/1

`/^-?([0-9]{1,2},?)?([0-9]{3},?){1,2}$/`

Comment: Friend a query, if I want to support this amount: 12

Answer (score 0):

This regex should supply you with what you want or point you in a direction:
`-?([0-9]{1,2},)?([0-9]{3},)?[0-9]{3}`

Comment: Friend a query, if I want to support this amount: 12

Answer (score 0):

This will match an optional leading sign `[-+]?`
followed by *either*
 a string of one or more digits `\d+` *or*
 a 1-3 digit string `\d{1,3}` followed by one more more groups of comma-3-digits `,\d{3}`

Putting it all together:

```
/^[-+]?((\d+)|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+))$/
```

I have grouped them with parentheses `()` to make it clear, but be aware this creates capturing groups.

```
var rgx = /^[-+]?((\d+)|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+))$/
var matched = "+813,823".match(rgx);  // ==> ["+813,823", "813,823", undefined, "813,823", ",823"]
```

You would want `matched[0]` to get the whole match.

Comment: Friend a query, if I want to support this amount: 12