# Validation Regex for quantities with centesimal …?

Tags: javascript, validation

Hello to the community I have a query, I need a validation Regex, for amounts without decimals, that consider valid the following structure.

**99,999,999**

(With maximum number of characters of 8, not counting the commas)

Take the following cases as an example, these numbers do not have to be exactly.

```
0               -> Ok
12              -> Ok
123             -> Ok
1234            -> Ok
12345           -> Ok
123456          -> Ok
1234567         -> Ok
12345678        -> Ok
123,4           -> Ok
123,45          -> Ok
123,456         -> Ok
123,456,7       -> Ok
123,456,78      -> Ok

123456789       -> Failed
123,456,789     -> Failed
123,45,6,78     -> Failed
12,3,45,6,78    -> Failed
12,345,678.50   -> Failed
12,456,7ab      -> Failed
0.50            -> Failed
```

I have only been able to validate the size of 8 numerical characters:

```
var regex8 = /^-?([0-9]{1,8})?$/;
```

I wait for your comments.

Thank you.

Comment: `/^-?(?:\d{1,8}|(?:\d{3},)?(?:\d{1,3}|\d{3},\d{1,2}))$/` like that?

Comment: Validation failed with amount: 123456789

Comment: ain't that in your definition? `123456789       -> Failed`

Comment: If that validation was missing

Comment: `If that validation was missing` don't understand that comment. If that's not what you meant, that `123456789` should fail, could you please update your question and explain what exactly the valid structure is; what values should return true, and wich should not. And how does `99,999,999` work with the defined structure? I'd have expected it to be `999,999,99`.

Comment: If you update it now.

Comment: I provided an answer, and tested it against the cases you specified.

Comment: Take the following cases as an example, these numbers do not have to be exactly.

Comment: Do you want all examples above to be valid except for 0.50, since it has a decimal point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation Regex for quantities with centesimal and without centesimal ...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990338/validation-regex-for-quantities-with-centesimal-and-without-centesimal)

Comment: You say that you "consider valid the following structure **99,999,999**" but then you say "123,456,78 -> Ok" which has **2** trailing digits and does **not** match the given structure, and is not a proper centesimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to validate a quantity from zero up to the value ninety-nine million nine-hundred and ninety-nine thousand nine-hundred and ninety-nine — with or without comma separators.

You say *"for amounts without decimals, that consider valid the following structure. **99,999,999**"*

But your test cases don't reflect the description you have written, for example
`123,4` does **not** fit the described format, though you say it is "Ok".

To match proper numbers, apart from what your test cases show, you want either a string of 1 to 8 digits `\d{1,8}` ***or*** a grouped set of up to 8 digits with properly placed commas.  A comma always precedes exactly 3 digits: `,\d{3}` and you can have two groups of those: `(,\d{3}){0,2}`.

Using parentheses to group the two alternatives, this gives `(\d{1,8})|(\d{1,2}(,\d{3}){0,2})`
or anchored to start and end of input: `^((\d{1,8})|(\d{1,2}(,\d{3}){0,2}))$`

This will ***not*** pass the tests you propose, but ***will*** match actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The test cases provided check for aligned three digits commas and decimal point, therefore here is the regular expression we need:

```
var r= /\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?/;
```

The other case, check if the number is decimal or not, without considering commas; So, the last test case is the only not decimal one. Then, here is its regular expression.

```
var r=  /[0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/;
```

I wrote a simple snippet to validate all cases you posted

```
var valid= ["0"
    ,"12"
    ,"123"
    ,"1234"
    ,"12345"           
    ,"123456"          
    ,"1234567"         
    ,"12345678"        
    ,"123,4"       
    ,"123,45"          
    ,"123,456"         
    ,"123,456,7"       
    ,"123,456,78"];        


var invalid= [
    ,"123456789"     
    ,"123,456,789"     
    ,"123,45,6,78"    
    ,"12,3,45,6,78"    
    ,"12,345,678.50"   
    ,"12,456,7ab"  
    ,"0.50" ];         


     var r= /\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+)?/;
     //or: according to your logic [0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/;

         valid.forEach(string=>{
            var isDecimal = string.match(r);
            console.log(string+ "::"+ !!isDecimal);
         });

        invalid.forEach(string=>{
            var isDecimal = string.match(r);
            console.log(string+ "::"+ !!!isDecimal);
         });
```

Comment: Take the following cases as an example, these numbers do not have to be exactly.

Comment: What are test cases that fail with the current regex? it would be helpful to provide them so I can update the answer.